# Django URLconf not matching localhost root

Tags: python, django

I'm sure that there is a very simple answer to this question, but I have tried all the other solutions I have seen, and cannot get it to work. I am using an include in the project urls.py at the root to my app urls.py root, but am getting a 404 error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My project urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls'))
]
```

And my app urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.login),
    re_path(r'^profile/$', views.profile),
]
```

Comment: Try including the trailing (in this case, the only) slash, i.e. `path('/', include('app.urls'))`.

Comment: I tried it, and this is what the 404 error message says:

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
/
The current path, ^/$, didn't match any of these.

Comment: What url are you attempting to browse out to?

Comment: I'm browsing to the root, localhost:8000/

Comment: If I change the project URLconf to path('main/', include('app.urls') and browse to localhost:8000/main/, then it works, but not path('', include('app.urls') at localhost:8000/

Comment: I figured out the problem, the trailing / on localhost:8000/ was messing up the connection to the root